# SQL Oracle data aggregation for statistical measurements (max,min, percentile)

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregation

Need to calculate max, min, median,percentile(.1,.25,.75) of expected default frequecies(edf) for the financial sector in each country within the database. I am provided  with individual company business day edf for a number of countries. Essentially the financial sector will include edf for companies (a1,a2...) from banking  + companies (b1,b2....) from investmebt funds + ....etc--> and do this for every country. Whenever I execute my query I return only individual company data within fin sector for each country. The problem is to aggregate these edf's such that when I select MAX(EDF) it gives me the **maximum edf for that day for the financial sector within the particular country** (the same of min and percentiles)  The code w/t the attempted aggregation:

```
select EDFDATE_EOM,mkmvid1,cinc,edf1,MAX(edf1),MIN(edf1),median(edf1),
  PERCENTILE_CONT (.1) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY edf1) AS "10TH",
  PERCENTILE_CONT (.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY edf1) AS "25TH",
  PERCENTILE_CONT (.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY edf1) AS "50TH",
  PERCENTILE_CONT (.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY edf1) AS "75TH",
  PERCENTILE_CONT (.90) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY edf1) AS "90TH"

from
(
select EDFDATE_EOM,mkmvid as mkmvid1,cinc, edf1 
FROM
(
SELECT MAX(EDFDATE) as "EDFDATE_EOM"  
FROM CRP.V_COMPANY_CONTENT
where edfdate>='1Jan2014'
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM EDFDATE), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM EDFDATE), EXTRACT(day FROM EDFDATE)
),
(
SELECT EDFDATE, mkmvid,cinc,mkmvindcode,edf1 
FROM CRP.V_COMPANY_CONTENT
WHERE MKMVINDCODE IN ('N06','N23','N24','N29','N30','N31','N32','N46','N47','N48')   
and  edfdate >= '1Jan2014'
and edfdate < '1Jan2015'
and cinc in ('BEL','DEU','IRL','GRC','ESP','FRA','ITA','LUX','NLD' ,'AUT','PRT','SLV','SVK','FIN','EST','LVA','LTU')

)
where EDFDATE_EOM = EDFDATE
), CRP.COMPANY_MAPPING
where CRP.COMPANY_MAPPING.MKMVID = mkmvid1
group by EDFDATE_EOM,mkmvid1,,cinc,edf1 
order by 1,3;
```

edfdate_eom--end of month date

edfdate--business day

mkmvid--company id

cinc--country of incorporation

edf1--expected 1yr default frequency

mkmvindcode--industry code (n06 to n48; this is the fin sector that I want to construct)

If you need any more clarification please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the measures separate for each country and industry code use the [analytic example](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions127.htm#SQLRF00687) of the  `PERCENTILE_CONT`

```
 PERCENTILE_CONT (.1) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY edf1)
    OVER (PARTITION BY cinc,mkmvid1)
```

If this is not the answer, pls simplify your question to focus on what you want to reach.